# Numerical solution of Fourier-Forand CDF

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to find a numerical solution of the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) of the Fournier-Forand phase function, which describes scattering angles of photons in water. I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.oceanopticsbook.info/view/monte_carlo_simulation/introduction),

According to the tutorial, "*to determine the polar scattering angle, we draw a $ U[0,1]$ random number  $ \mathfrak{r}$ as always and solve*"
 $\displaystyle \mathfrak{r} = 2 \pi \int_0^{\psi} \tilde{\beta}(\psi')\,\sin \psi' \,d \psi'$:

*"In general this equation must be solved numerically...when the phase function is defined by tabulated data at a finite number of scattering angles and is fit with a spline (or other) function to generate a continuous function of scattering angle."*

Now, I have tabulated data at a finite number of scatting angles $\mathfrak(\psi) $ in Matlab, and I can fit this with a spline. However, from there I'm a bit lost. I don't really understand to substitute my tabulated data for $\mathfrak(\tilde{\beta})$. I have tried integrating by parts (since both $\mathfrak(\tilde{\beta})$ and $\mathfrak(\sin \psi)$ are functions of $\mathfrak \psi$?) as follows:

Let $\mathfrak u = \tilde{\beta}, dv/d\psi = sin\psi$

Then $v = \int sin\psi =-cos(\psi)$

To obtain $du/d\psi$ I take the gradient of my tabulated data. My tabulated data looks very similar to the purple curve in the first figure shown [here](http://www.oceanopticsbook.info/view/scattering/the_fournierforand_phase_function). I think put all that together using the standard formula for integration by parts.

Evaluating this at $\psi = \pi$ should yield $ \mathfrak{r} = 1$, but that's not the result I get.

Can anyone give me any directions as to how to approach this problem? Thanks!